# Is it possible to change Orange3 on-canvas widget caption?

Tags: python, orange

I am developing Orange3 widget. Is there any way to change on-canvas widget caption in execution time?

[image: My widget]

Comment: Does right-clicking and choosing `Rename (F2)` in the context menu work for you?

Comment: I am asking how to do it from widget code...

Comment: That's widget's `name` class attribute, I think. No further control over it.